# What is the fastest way to get the value of e?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic

What is the most optimised algorithm which finds the value of e with moderate accuracy?

I am looking for a comparison between optimised approaches giving more importance to speed than high precision.

Edit: By moderate accuracy I mean upto 6-7 decimal places.
But if there is a HUGE difference in speed, then I can settle with 4-5 places.

Comment: Define "moderate accuracy".

Comment: Ask the FPU for it. *runs*

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. What do you mean? ```optimised approaches and the approaches which certain languages use built-in, which trade speed for higher accuracy.``` Getting the value, depending on your type, is just a lookup in some precomputed table, right?

Comment: Ya. My bad. That beats the purpose. I edited the question.

Comment: The fastest algorithm for a given precision is just to return an appropriate value.  That's why we usually talk about how fast an algorithm *converges* towards the exact value as you let it run longer.

Comment: Just stare the value as a constant and return it. Takes **O(1)** time & space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **basic datatype**

   As mentioned in the comments `6-7` decimal places is too small accuracy to do this by an algorithm. Instead use a constant which is the fastest way anyway for this.

   ```
   const double e=2.7182818284590452353602874713527;
   ```

   If **FPU** is involved the constant is usually stored there too... Also having single constant occupies much less space than a function that computes it ...
2. **finite accuracy**

   Only once `bignum`s are involved then has any merit to use algorithm to compute `e`. The algo depends on target accuracy. Again for smaller accuracies are predefined constants used:

   ```
   e=2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995957496696762772407663035354759457138217852516642742746639193200305992181741359662904357290033429526059563073813232862794349076323382988075319525101901157383418793070215408914993488416750924476146066808226480016847741185374234544243710753907774499206955170189
   ```

   but usually in hex format for faster and more precise manipulation:

   ```
   e=2.B7E151628AED2A6ABF7158809CF4F3C762E7160F38B4DA56A784D9045190CFEF324E7738926CFBE5F4BF8D8D8C31D763DA06C80ABB1185EB4F7C7B5757F5958490CFD47D7C19BB42158D9554F7B46BCED55C4D79FD5F24D6613C31C3839A2DDF8A9A276BCFBFA1C877C56284DAB79CD4C2B3293D20E9E5EAF02AC60ACC93ECEBh
   ```

   For limited/finite accuracy and best speed is the [PSLQ](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PSLQAlgorithm.html) algorithm best. My understanding is that it is algorithm to find relation between real number and integer iterations.

   - [here is my favourite PSLQ up to 800 digits of Pi PSLQ example](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node12.html)
3. **arbitrary accuracy**

   For arbitrary or "fixed" precision you need algorithm that is with variable precision. This is what I use in my `arbnum` class:

   ```
   e=(1+1/x)^x where x -> +infinity
   ```

   If you chose `x` as power of 2 realize that `x` is just single set bit of the number and `1/x` has predictable bit-width. So the `e` will be obtained with single division and `pow`. Here an example:

   ```cpp
   arbnum arithmetics_e()          // e computation min(_arbnum_max_a,arbnum_max_b)*5 decimals
       {                           // e=(1+1/x)^x  ... x -> +inf
       int i; arbnum c,x;
       i=_arbnum_bits_a; if (i>_arbnum_bits_b) i=_arbnum_bits_b; i>>=1;
       c.zero(); c.bitset(_arbnum_bits_b-i); x.one(); x/=c; c++;
       for (;!x.bitget(_arbnum_bits_b);x>>=1) c*=c;    //=pow(c,x);
       return c;
       }
   ```

   Where `_arbnum_bits_a,_arbnum_bits_b` is the number of bits before and after decimal point in binary. So it break down to some bit operations, one bignum division and single power by squaring. Beware that multiplication and division is not that simple with bignums and usually involves Karatsuba or worse ...

   There are also polynomial approaches out there that does not require `bignum` arithmetics similar to compute `Pi`. The idea is to compute chunk of binary bits per iteration without affecting the previously computed bits (too much). They should be faster but as usual for any optimizations that depends on the implementation and HW it runs on.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For reference see Brother's formula here  : https://www.intmath.com/exponential-logarithmic-functions/calculating-e.php